# D3.JS bar graph column offset while adding new data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, javascript-objects

I'm currently working with D3.JS attempting to add to an existing graph every 24 hours.  Using JSON data like this:

```
[{"name": "bill", "val": 28}, {"name": "kevin", "val": 46}, {"name": "ryan", "val": 23},{"name": "ville", "val": 56}]
```

I have a frequency value on my Y axis, and a username on my xaxis.  I think I have my placement function correct, but when adding a new column (although the offset should stay the same) all columns are shifted out of place.  The goal is to be able to add columns (new data) and keep the columns (rects) above the proper username.

Here is my current working code:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="data/json" src="data.json"></script> 

<style>
#chart rect{
  fill: #4aaeea;
}
#chart text{
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end; 
}
.axis text{
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path, .axis line{
  fill: none;
  stroke : #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
body{
  background: #1a1a1a;
  color : #eaeaea;
  padding : 5px;
}
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"</div>
<script>
var margin ={top:20, right:30, bottom:30, left:40},
    width=960-margin.left - margin.right, 
    height=500-margin.top-margin.bottom;
// scale to ordinal because x axis is not numerical
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
//scale to numerical value by height
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var chart = d3.select("#chart")  
              .append("svg")  //append svg element inside #chart
              .attr("width", width+(2*margin.left)+margin.right)    //set width
              .attr("height", height+margin.top+margin.bottom);  //set height
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom");  //orient bottom because x-axis will appear below the bars
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("left");
var data;
d3.json("http://localhost:8000/data.json", function(error, data){
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.name}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.val})]);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                  .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                      return "translate("+x(d.name)+", 0)";
                    });
 console.log(margin.left); 
  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d.val); 
      })
      .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return x(margin.left + 2);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return height - y(d.val); 
      })
      .attr("width", Math.min.apply(null, [x.rangeBand()-2, 100]));
      //.attr("width", x.rangeBand());  //set width base on range on ordinal data
  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", (margin.left * 2.2))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.val) })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.val; });

  chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+ height+")")        
        .call(xAxis);

  chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+",0)")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");
});
function type(d) {
    d.name = +d.name; // coerce to number
    return d;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I thought ordinal scales needed a `domain`... maybe `.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.name;}))` ?

Comment: Also, your type function is useless (and rather dangerous, it would simply erase the name from your data if you call it)

Comment: @tarulen I have since removed that function - thanks for pointing that out!  I do wrap all of my d3 code with my load function for json right?

Comment: yes, everything that needs data must be wrapped into the json callback. You can keep function definitions outside if you prefer

Comment: @tarulen Thanks!  Just wanted to see what best practice was.  (or if that was the origin of my issue)

Comment: I don't understand this part: "when adding a new column (...) all columns are shifted out of place" : there is a single drawing function in your code, so there's no way to shift anything (except by reloading the page, but then everything is redrawn from scratch). Could you be more explicit of what triggers the new column drawing?

Comment: @tarulen Yes, by adding a new column I mean updating the json to contain a new value and reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a few adjustments to the positional attributes of `g` elements containing bar `rect` elements and `dx` and `dy` attributes of text elements.

Hope this working code snippet helps.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// scale to ordinal because x axis is not numerical
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

//scale to numerical value by height
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg") //append svg element inside #chart
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) //set width
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom); //set height

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom"); //orient bottom because x-axis will appear below the bars

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var data = [{
  "name": "bill",
  "val": 28
}, {
  "name": "kevin",
  "val": 46
}, {
  "name": "ryan",
  "val": 23
}, {
  "name": "ville",
  "val": 56
}];

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.name
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.val
})]);

var barWidth = Math.min.apply(null, [x.rangeBand() - 2, 100]);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ", " + y(d.val) + ")";
  });

bar.append("rect")
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("x", barWidth - 10)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.val);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth);

bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", barWidth - 10)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("dx", barWidth / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.val;
  });

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

function type(d) {
  d.name = +d.name; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

```css
#chart rect {
  fill: #4aaeea;
}
#chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" </div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble re-creating your snippet outside of stackoverflow.  This is the current status when running it. 
https://i.imgur.com/uFUFkJs.png

The only difference is that I'm loading a json file.  Any other ideas?

Current code: https://github.com/kzisme/logViz/blob/master/index.html

Comment: It seems like that the x axis is shifted a little to the left(May be about 40 pixels - margin.left). Check if transform of attribute of x axis group element is same as `.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")` as in the snippet.

Comment: Here is what I get when I attempt to add a new data value (from within my json file).  Am I properly appending?  the axis group element is matching the snippet - and can be seen here https://github.com/kzisme/logViz/blob/master/index.html#L106

Comment: I think the main difference between this code and the original is the use of `barWidth` where in the orignal you had ``x(margin.left + 2)`... which does not work when `x` is an ordinal scale.

Comment: @Gilsha It also seems your snippet is showing incorrect placement of x axis.  Everything is properly aligned, but the x-axis is left offset as well.

Comment: @tarulen What is the suggested fix then?  I'm running the snippet and still confused (since the snippet is wrong it seems) .  Just so the offsets are correct each time I add data.  (that's my goal)